# Cannot start Protractor tests with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, mocha.js

Yesterday everything was working fine for me. It broke just by itself. When I try to run an automated test with protractor, it runs Google Chrome, but over it appear a blank console. and nothing behind it loads. The URL behind it stays "data;". If I close that blank console, it opens by itself again. If I set the browser at the config file to be Firefox, it runs without any problem.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, and I've tried updating the webdriver-manager, and reinstalling protractor. In fact, I just installed everything fresh today, and I'm still getting this exact behavior from Chrome

Comment: --EDIT: Nope. Protractor was out of date GLOBALLY. I'd recommend ensuring that your global install is 2.5 or later by typing
>protractor --version

Answer (score 2):

This bug appeared after the chrome update for many people, the solution that worked for me and other people in SO is reinstall protractor.

Comment: make sure you have version 2.5 or later

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running webdriver-manager update to update the selenium and chrome drivers?